# как создать inner middleware в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, middleware

создаю бота. нужно, чтобы миддлварь проверяла работу лишь некоторых хэндлеров, но не всех сразу - есть инлайн клавиатура для игры, нужно, чтобы после нажатия на любую из кнопок на ней, запускался таймер. думал реализовать такое с помощью inner мидлвари, которая после фильтрации происходит. но нигде не могу найти как ее создать. помогите пожалуйста